# QuickIONET: FileInfo object for non existent file

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to create an instance of `QuickIOFileInfo` for a non existent file (which is passed as a paramter to a method and created/written in this method) but I am getting a `SchwabenCode.QuickIO.PathNotFoundException` with the message `The system cannot find the file specified.`

So far, so good (or not).

But since there is an `.Exists` property, there surely is a way for an instance of an non existent file... How do I create the instance?

Answer (score 0):

A QuickIOFileInfo represents a file/path to a file on the computer, it must not be used for file creation. Please take a look at [QuickIOFile.Create](https://quickio.net/Docs/v2.0.1.0/#type/QuickIOFile?Create5)

Comment: Can you provide a link where the documentation says that the file must exist? `FileInfo` objects can point to non-existent files (which imho makes sense, the info is, that this file does not exist). Also the documentation says *Nearly identical signature of methods. So a simple replacement is possible* but not all `FileInfo` objects can be used for creating `QuickIOFileInfo`...

Comment: Well the documentation is quite explicit: all of QuickIOFileInfo constructors take a file path or similar as parameters. And no a FileInfo object represent a file on the computer: "Initializes a new instance of the FileInfo class, which acts as a wrapper for a file path."

Comment: By "represent a file on the computer" I meant a path to a file btw (or nothing if there's no file at the specified path).